# Conflicting overloads al hacer herencia en kotlin

Tags: kotlin, herencia

Hola que tal estoy empezando a aprender a programar orientado a objetos en kotlin y estaba practicando la parte de herencias con un ejemplo simple de armas, me sale este error el cual no se que lo causa.
[image: Error en el código]

La clase Espada esta heredando de la clase Armas la cual es esta
[image: Clase espada]

Comment: Te recomiendo colocar el código en texto y no en imagen, así nos facilitas la labor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo haría algo así.

```
open class Arma(val nombre: String = "",
            val tipo: String = "",
            val rareza: String = "",
            val daño: Int = 0,
            val durabilidad: Double = 100.0,
            val precision: Int = 0,
            val rango: Int = 0,
            val dureza: String = "")

class Espada(nombre: String = "",
             tipo: String = "",
             rareza: String = "",
             daño: Int = 0,
             durabilidad: Double = 100.0,
             precision: Int = 0,
             rango: Int = 0,
             dureza: String = "",
             var filo: String = "",
             var tipo_mango: String = "",
             var tipo_magia: String = "",
             var tipo_fuerza: String = ""): Arma(nombre, tipo,rareza, daño, durabilidad, precision, rango, dureza) {

             }



fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val escalibur = Espada()
    escalibur.tipo_fuerza = "Si"
    escalibur.filo = "Doble"
    println("${escalibur.filo}")
    println("${escalibur.tipo_fuerza}")
}
```

O utilizaría una interfaz para Arma.

Espero haberte ayudado